# Android NDK: Two prebuilt shared libraries, but one of them depends on the other

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, rust, libsodium

I'm writing an Android application that relies on two prebuilt shared libraries (A and B). Both libraries are configured to work with the armeabi and armeabi-v7a architectures.

The first prebuilt library, A, is libsodium. The second prebuilt library, B, is a Rust library that depends on libsodium. When compiling the Rust prebuilt library, libsodium is used as a dependency.

Right now, I want to use my two prebuilt libraries, A & B, in my Android application. Loading A using System.loadLibrary() works just fine. But when I load B, there's an error that B can't find a method defined in A:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "crypto_sign_ed25519_detached" referenced by "libB.so"...`

My Android.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := sodium
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libsodium.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium.h $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium/
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := rust
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/librust.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium.h $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium/
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sodium
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := rust-manager
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := rust-manager.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := rust sodium
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/ $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium.h $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/sodium/
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The rust-manager.c file is my C wrapper generated using javah that contains C functions that map my native Java functions to the Rust library, but I think it's negligible at this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I take it that you've already loaded library A when loading library B? Can you try `arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D libA.so | grep crypto_sign_ed25519_detached` and similarly for libB.so? (You find the `nm` binary in `NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.*/prebuilt/*/bin`.)

Comment: That's right, A is being loaded before B. Just ran nm and received the following outputs:

`T crypto_sign_ed25519_detached for libA.so
U crypto_sign_ed25519_detached for libB.so`

Any idea what this means?

Comment: I assume the former had a nonzero hex address printed before the `T`, while the latter had empty space before the `U`? This just means that libA.so has a definition for the symbol, and libB.so has an undefined symbol with that name. So given that, it does seem correct.

Comment: Oh interesting. Could this mean that libB has been configured incorrectly or that some undesirable optimization could have occurred that omitted this method from the final object?

Comment: No, it means that libB uses this function (or variable), and libA provides it - which all seems just correct, just as it should be. The questions is why it isn't found when you already have loaded libA, when trying to load libB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a days worth of work, the problem was with the version of libsodium that I was using (1.0.6). I found that the undefined symbols when running ndk-build vary based on the version used. Using libsodium v1.0.3 solved my problems!